# Сохранение таблицы в БД

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Имеется динамическая таблица. Задача состоит в том чтобы после заполнения таблицы информацией по кнопке все данные уходили в таблицу в базу которая на лету должна создаватся.

HTML:

```
    <p><strong>Имя таблицы</strong></p>
<p><input maxlength="25" size="40" ></p>
  <table>
     <tbody id="contacts">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"><a href="#" onclick="addContact (); return false">Добавьте контакт</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width = 20 ></td>
      <td>Имя </td>
      <td>Email</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JS

```
    function addContact ()
{
var tb = document.getElementById ('contacts'),
    ro = tb.insertRow (-1), ce = ro.insertCell (-1);
if (tb.rows.length == 2) ce.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
else
   {
   var im = document.createElement ('img');
   im.src = 'del.jpg';
   im.onclick = function () {tb.deleteRow (this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)}
   ce.appendChild (im);
   }
NUM = (!self.NUM) ? 1 : ++NUM;
var ce = ro.insertCell (-1), inp = document.createElement ('input');
inp.name = 'name' + NUM; ce.appendChild (inp);
var ce = ro.insertCell (-1), inp = document.createElement ('input');
inp

.name = 'email' + NUM; ce.appendChild (inp);
var ce = ro.insertCell (-1), inp = document.createElement ('input');
inp.name = 'text' + NUM; ce.appendChild (inp);
}
```

Comment: Интересно, а зачем каждый раз создавать новую таблицу? Если вы каждый раз добавляете контакт, судя по коду.

Comment: Это просто шаблон, на деле будут генерироватся страницы с уникальным контентом

Comment: как вариант можно обернуть всю таблицу в форму и поля с контентом сделать инпутами или текстареа, а потом сабмитить форму и отправлять ее на пхп файл где вы ее перехватите и отправите в базу

Comment: А как это сделать?! И так инпуты